# Git: How to restore the dates for the commits after rebasing?

Tags: git, gitlab

I started a Git project a while back, and one of the very first files that I commited was a `main.c` file that never really needed any updating after the initial commit.

As I went through the project, I saw a small formatting flaw that I did not think would warrant the need to be done through a commit. I decided to simply squash it with an older commit (the only other commit) related to this file.

As it was an early commit, I decided to do `git rebase -i --root` and push the changes.

The problem I have now is that **ALL** the commits on GitLab now shows that they have been commited today. This is a problem as this was a school project, and the teacher checks the commit logs as a grading factor and will get the impression that the entire project was pushed once.

**NOTE:**
Some of my old branches that were merged are still on the repo with the correct dates.

Is there anyway for me to revert this situation? Or to manually set dates for the commits (visible on GitLab online)?

Comment: It doesn't work. The online version still shows all the commits dated as today. :(

Comment: The commit date are all set to: Wed Dec 27 20:03:38 2017 -0500. Author dates are all different and varying.

Comment: It didn't work. It now shows : `CommitDate: Wed Dec 27 20:35:23 2017 -0500` for all the commits.

Comment: `--root` uses the interactive rebase code, which does not support `--committer-date-is-author-date`. You can use `filter-branch`, or rebase without `--root`.  It's all pretty messy, no matter how you go about it...

Comment: The commit date can be easily forged by `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=<date> git <command>`. It's not valid evaluation criteria, but maybe don't let your teacher know it. `--committer-date-is-author-date` can't work with `-i`. You could try `git cherry-pick` and `git reset` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=<date> git commit <--amend>` to squash and reapply commits.

Comment: I just found out through a long list of issues opened on Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/15868. Seems like GitLab is displaying commit dates unlike other Git providers whom displays author date.

Comment: `git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE'`

Comment: @PetSerAI - I have an entirely different issue now, and I am not even sure what happened. The rebase commands somehow got my `master` branch "disconnected" from the other branches. My Gitk and remote GitLab graph show 2 seperate graphs with the same commits but different SHA numbers. Trying out these commands got myself in a bigger mess then I already was in.

Comment: @PetSerAI - And I can't see what the old commands were since the deleted comments... I cloned a test repo and tested the new one you proposed and it does not work. In fact, it deletes all the other branches.